# Does $\lVert S_Nf-f\rVert_{\infty}\to 0$ imply $\lVert S_Nf-f\rVert_{L^2}\to 0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

> Does $\lVert S_Nf-f\rVert_{\infty}\to 0$ imply $\lVert S_Nf-f\rVert_{L^2}\to 0$

I have a proof for the first case, under the assumption that $f$ is $C^1$ and real valued (also $1$ periodic) $\lVert S_Nf-f\rVert_{\infty}$ tends to $0$ with growing $N$, but in the second case $f$ is now complex valued, but still $C^1$ so is there a problem ?

(with $S_Nf=\sum\limits_{\lvert n\rvert\le N}\hat f_ne^{i2\pi n x}$ and  $\hat{ f}_n=\int_0^1f(x)e^{-i2\pi n x}dx$)

Comment: Are you looking at $L^2([0,1])$ or at $L^2(\Bbb R)$ ?

Comment: $L^p([0,1]) \subset L^q([0,1])$ whenever $p > q$,  and $(L^q(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})) \subset L^p(\mathbb{R})$ again whenever $p > q$. in particular an inclusion $X \subset Y$ where $X,Y$ are Banach spaces means that $\|x_n-x\|_{X} \to 0 \implies \|x-x_n\|_Y \to 0$

Comment: @Watson It is only written that $L^2(\mathbb T,\mathbb C)$ is a Hilbert space with scalar product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$, so I assume in $L^2([0,1])$

Comment: $\mathbb{T} = [0,1]$, i.e. you are considering $L^2([0,1])$

Comment: @user1952009 Why $[0,1]$?

Comment: @ClementC. because his Fourier series are $1$ periodic

Comment: Well, yes. What makes you interpret the question this very specific way, is there a reason? @user1952009

Comment: For me, it looks like $\Bbb T = S^1$ is the circle, which is $[0,1] / 0 \sim 1$.

Comment: @ClementC. : $\mathbb{T}$ is always a $1$ dimensional torus, here for his question no need to say anything more than $\mathbb{T} = [0,1]$ , I don't see the point

Comment: OK, I must be misinterpreting the qestion, or completely out of it. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|g_n - f\|_{\infty} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$, then

$$\int_0^1 |g_n-f|^2 \leq \int_0^1 \|g_n - f\|_{\infty}^2 = \|g_n - f\|_{\infty} ^2 \to 0$$ when $n \to \infty$,
so that $\|g_n-f\|_{L^2(0,1)} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: exactly what I thought and It is  also not an issue that $f$ is in the second case complex valued ?

Comment: @yasabur : this doesn't matter, since the modulus $|g_n - f|$ of the complex-valued function $g_n - f$ is bounded from above by $\|g_n - f\|_{\infty}$. Similarly, the $L^2$-norm is defined thanks to the (square of the) modulus $|g_n - f|$.